# Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 2.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

We have a hadoop cluster of 625 nodes. But some of them are centos 6 (python 2.6) and some are centos 7 (python 2.7). So how can I resolve this as I am getting this error constantly.

Answer (score 0):

Install at least Python 2.7 on each node and configure `SPARK_PYTHON` environment variable to point to the required installation. Spark doesn't support mixed environments and doesn't support Python 2.6 anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I have 2.7 on all the nodes. But I cannot change spark-conf file to point to this python version as the cluster is used by different teams. Can I specify the path to 2.7 installation from spark-submit command?